# How do you initialize a constant bias in tf.layers.keras.Conv2D?

Tags: python, tensorflow, initialization, deep-learning, keras

So, the title pretty much says it all. The default argument is, `bias_initializer='zeros'`, but I intend on initializing with a constant value of 0.1. I'm assuming this is a very easy question to answer, but I can't seem to make sense of the documentation for this on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Keras-way:** ([doc](https://keras.io/initializers/#constant))

```
keras.initializers.Constant(0.1)
```

**Tensorflow-way:** ([doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant_initializer))

```
tf.constant_initializer(0.1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `tf.constant_initializer` ([documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant_initializer))

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. So lets assume my code reads `Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), bias_initializer='zeros')` 


Would I do the following:
`constant = tf.constant_initializer(0.1)`

`Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), bias_initializer=constant)`

Comment: You would need to specify the correct shape of your bias, so for example, `constant = tf.constant_initializer(np.full(10, 0.1))` if you need a bias vector of length 10.